# Is it possible to send a field name as a variable into Django's .annotate

Tags: python, django, filter, annotations

Is it possible to send a field name as a variable?

The following works (Note: myqso is a filtered queryset based on a model with a field called LocTypeNum):

```
myqsnew = myqso.annotate(newloctypenum=F('LocTypeNum')+10)
myqsop = [{'the_new_loctypenum':p.newloctypenum} for p in myqsnew]
```

But I want to send LocTypeNum in as a variable. Is there a better/faster method for making calculated fields and using variables as field names? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this is example `LocTypeNum` is just a string. So you can just replace with variable:

```
somefield = "some_field"
SomeModel.objects.all().aggregate(somename=Sum(F(somefield))
```

You can even path aggragetion name as varaiable:

```
SomeModel.objects.all().aggregate(**{somename: Sum(F(somefield)})
```